# Why are my photos taken with Kodak Portra 400 and Fuji C200 coming out grayish?

Tags: exposure, resolution

I'm fairly new to film photography. I have a Canon AE1 and I'm kind of discovering how to use it, understand exposure etc. I've done photos with Kodak color plus 200 and they came out nicely, recently I did some with Kodak Portra 400 and Fuji C200, but I developed them in a different place and some came out grayish and kind of hazy.
I wanted help to understand is it an exposure problem? is the new lab not great ? is it both ?
Anything helps.

**Kodak portra 400**
When I used the Portra on this pictures it was a very nice day with a blue sky (here it appears white/non existent...)
[image: Portra 400 1]
[image: Portra 400 2]
[image: Portra 400 3]

Scans:
[image: Scan 1]
[image: Scan 2]
[image: Scan 3]

**C200**
I know I used the C200 on a hazy/not very bright day so I guess for this one, this might be the issue ?
[image: C22]
[image: C22 2]

Scans:
[image: Scan 1]
[image: Scan 2]

Comment: When I was shooting color film long ago, which included a lot of Kodak and Fuji 200, I found that nice blue skies usually came out white.  A polarizing filter was a necessary part of my kit, usually turned to darken the sky as much as possible.  It brought out the contrast on snowy mountains nicely as well.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the lab.  Their printing hardware/software may be calibrated for a different film type.  You can photograph a color card with the film you are using as the first exposure on the roll.  The lab can then re-calibrate based on the color card photo.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add contrast with a photo editing tool, labs generally scan pretty flat to give you the most leeway to edit afterwards.